# Using sum method in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I am trying to sum up the values in a *generic collection*, I have used the same exact code to perform the this function in other pieces of my code but it seems to have an issue with the `ulong` data type?

The code

```
   Items.Sum(e => e.Value);
```

has the following error:

> Error  15  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: '`System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>>, System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>,float>)`' and '`System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>>, System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,ulong>,decimal?>`)

```
public class Teststuff : BaseContainer<int, ulong, ulong>
{
    public decimal CurrentTotal { get { return Items.Sum(e => e.Value); } }

    public override void Add(ulong item, int amount = 1)
    {
    }

    public override void Remove(ulong item, int amount = 1)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class BaseContainer<T, K, P>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pass in the owner of this container.
    /// </summary>
    public BaseContainer()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<T, K>();
    }

    public BaseContainer()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<T, K>();
    }

    public Dictionary<T, K> Items { get; private set; }
    public abstract void Add(P item, int amount = 1);
    public abstract void Remove(P item, int amount = 1);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Sum()` has no overload that returns a `ulong`, and the compiler can't decide which of the overloads that do exist to call.

You can help it decide with a cast:

```
Items.Sum(e => (decimal)e.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks I just changed all the ulongs to decimal, i'll accept this as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: @lakedoo: Note that if you change the type of `Value`, you don't need a cast.  Also, are you sure you don't want `long` instead?

Comment: Good point, yeah I am going with long it doesnt seem to have any issues with that. Thanks again!

Comment: @lakedoo Be careful of overflow issues. Summing `ulong`s together and expecting a `long` seems dangerous. Either your properties shouldn't be `ulong` to begin with (and if they do need that precision, your sum will fail), or you should write an extension for `Sum` that deals with `ulong`.

Comment: @jb1t's answer is the best answer. It is less risky (no overflow exceptions) and more efficient as it avoids casting every item in your list

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen yet on this issue. It works well in the controller cade and in the view. Thanks for the tip.@SLaks

Answer (score 9):

Agreed about `Sum()` has no overload that returns a `ulong`, and the compiler can't decide which of the overloads that do exist to call. However, if you cast to a long you can run into a `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

Instead you could create an extension method like this:

```
public static UInt64 Sum(this IEnumerable<UInt64> source)
{
    return source.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about casting and it uses native data type addition.